# Oracle Apex, create line chart

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have to build a Oracle Application with a line chart in it. The data for it comes from a database.

In the database, there are two columns, called `Datum; Number_VMs`. Column "Datum" is the date on which the entry was made, column "Number_VMs" is the amount of VMs that still exist.

The diagram should show, how many VMs still exist on the specific date. how do I need to write my SQL Query for that? Could someone help me with that?

Kind Regards

Comment: Maybe: `SELECT Datum, Sum(Number_VMs) AS SumV FROM tablename GROUP BY Datum;`

Comment: Hi, can I also add a filter to this, or do I need to change something drastically?

Comment: Yes, can add filter with WHERE or HAVING clause. Really basic SQL. Suggestion assume Datum is date only, no time components.

Comment: Yes, "Datum" is in the Format "DD.MM.YYYY", if this is important.

Comment: You are using international structure. I don't know if Oracle will have issue with that.  If you were using Access it would, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html.

Comment: OK, I will have a look into that...